# What is in eel sauce?

Tags: sauce, sushi

I've always love eating this dark eel sauce that goes with eel rolls at our favorite sushi restaurants. It's got a dark color it's sweet, a little salty, and slightly savory.

What is in eel sauce? What makes it sweet and so concentrated with flavor? Also, why is it called eel sauce?

Comment: I am sad to hear that there is soy in eel sauce. It is tough to do sushi while avoiding soy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Components:**

- sweet -> sugar+mirin (rice wine)
- salt -> soy
- savory -> soy+mirin+eel bones

At home, you probably won't be able to manage eel bones boiled down into stock. Ignoring that, it's all a matter of mixing and reducing.

Sugar+soy+mirin, reduce to 1/3, revel in the joy of caramel and salt and sharpness.

Comment: You could also just reduce teriyaki or tempura sauce if you have them lying around - they're all pretty similar in taste, minus the eel bones.

Comment: You could also possibly add some powdered dashi stock, for savory - it's not eel but it is made from fish and tends to add an umami flavor.

Comment: Heck, you might even be able to get away with sardines, very finely processed and strained, if you really cut the amount of soy. Experiment!

Comment: @Dave Griffith, Mirin is not rice wine vinegar; but rather a type of rice wine, that is similar to sake (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirin). Rice wine vinegar is something else (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_vinegar).

Comment: @TheDude I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The preparation is called [Kabayaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabayaki), hence the Eel sauce is also called Kabayaki sauce.

Ingredients list:

1. Hon Mirin: Alcohol & sweetness
2. Naturally fermented soy sauce: Umami & saltiness
3. Eel / fish bones: flavour(smell)